Why is the quasi-linear method of characteristics not a circular argument?
Consider the semi-linear first-order partial differential equation
$$u_t(t, x) + f(t, x) u_x(t, x) = g(t, x, u(t, x)) \, .$$
My understand is that to solve a partial differential equation we first assume that $u$ is an abstract solution to the equation and show that this constrains $u$ to have some specific algebraic form.
To solve the above, we assume $u$ solves the given equation. We show that if $\dot{x}(t) = f(t, x(t))$ then $z(t) \equiv u(t, x(t))$ satisfies $\dot{z}(t) = g(t, x(t), z(t))$ and this allows us to solve the problem since although we do not yet know $z(t)$ we can explicitly solve for $x(t)$ first and then $z(t)$.
Compare this with Burger's equation, $$u_t(t, x) + u(t, x) u_x(t, x) = 0 \, .$$
It is easy to understand that if $\dot{x}(t) = u(t, x(t))$ then $z(t) \equiv u(t, x(t))$ is constant but it is unclear to me how logically this allows us to solve the problem.
In practice, we just consider the system of ordinary differential equations
$$\begin{cases} \dot{x}(t) = z(t) \\ \dot{z}(t) = 0\end{cases}$$
but I don't understand why this is allowed as the statement "if $\dot{x}(t) = u(t, x(t))$ then $z(t) \equiv u(t, x(t))$ is constant" seems to have $\dot{x}(t) = u(t, x(t))$ as a precondition.

Very often the solution procedure is not like what you described.  Rather than proving that the solution must have a specific form, we make a guess at the form of a solution, and see what must be true in order for something of that form to satisfy the equation.  If we are lucky, we find something that is indeed a solution of the equation.

You also have to include initial/boundary conditions. If we know $u$ along some noncharacteristic curve in the $x$-$t$ plane, and we know that $u$ is constant along some set of lines, we can trace those lines back to that initial curve and use the fact that $u$ is constant along characteristic lines to obtain the solution at a given point
